# [TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'iter[Symbol.iterator]')] react-native

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, react-native

I am using react-redux and redux-persist in my react-native project it is working fine but when i tried to add object into redux state it is throwing this error

```
[TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'iter[Symbol.iterator]')]
```

My code inside reducer is

```
        case ADD_FILES_DURATION:
        console.log("data received",action.data);
        return {
            ...state,
            filesDuration: [...state.filesDuration, action.data]
        };
```

and my state initial values are

```
const initialState = {
trackSpeed: "1",
filesDuration: [],
}
```

and from my homescreen i am trying to insert data into redux like this

```
    const item = {
        folderName: folderName,
        track: trackName,
        duration: duration
    }
    addFileDuration(item);
```

it is working fine for other redux operation but whenever i am trying to run this it is giving above error

Please help if anyone knows how to resolve this or any suggestions ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After work around , i found what i was doing wrong

i was wrongly inserting data into redux that's the reason i was getting this error

So instead of this

```
   const item = {
    folderName: folderName,
    track: trackName,
    duration: duration
}
addFileDuration(item);
```

i used this

```
   const item = {
    "folderName": folderName,
    "track": trackName,
    "duration": duration
}
addFileDuration(item);
```

now it is working fine hope it may help anybody

Comment: i'm getting the same error and i really don't understand the cause, even from your explanation above.

Comment: try uninstalling and then reinstall the app, because sometimes it doesn't reflect store data instant

Answer (score 2):

This error made no sense to me as I was using another reducer with the same logic, turns out all you have to do is restart your project (I also deleted the app from my simulator)

Comment: Yes this also I found sometimes you need to restart your app it will work

Comment: uninstall and installing again worked for me

Answer (score 1):

I had the same error on my simulator when using react-native. The error info is like this:

> TypeError: null is not an object (evaluating 'iter[Symbol.iterator]')

Because I setValue as **null**, but expected as **Array**.